# Mulval installation problem

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to run mulval package on kubuntu 15.04. When I type "make" I get a follow error "GetCVID.java:26: error: package org.dom4j does not exist. \n import org.dom4j.Attribute"

Then there is a bunch of "Cannot find symbol 
symbol: class SAXReader 
location: class GetCVEID

I have mysql and xsb installed.

any help how to fix it, please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the `MULVALROOT` environment variable before being able to build the project, since the Makefile relies on it in order to find the location of several Java libraries.